# Logging selection from a context menu

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

//I'm trying to reproduce the example of context menus with the following code (taken from MDN).

```
browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: "log-selection",
  title: "Log '%s' to the console",
  contexts: ["selection"]
});

browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
  if (info.menuItemId == "log-selection") {
    console.log(info.selectionText);
  }
});
```

The problem is I can not see the logs in any kind of console: not in the Web console nor the navigator console (opened through the debugging button I `about:debugging`). So, where should I see the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is background code, you need to inspect the background page itself.

In Firefox, this is accessible through the corresponding `Debug` button on `about:debugging`.

Reading through [Anatomy of a WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension) is also recommended.

Comment: Hello Xan, I already read it, I swear you. But it is not being logged. You can check it by installing this project and then opening the debug window as you sayd: https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/context-menu-demo

Comment: Now I updated Firefox to version 55.0b3 and it is the same, I can not see the logs in any console

Comment: Found. It may be a bug. It is in the browser's console but not when you access from about:debuging

Answer (score 0):

It is in the Browser console that you can access from MAY+CTRL+ALT+I, not from the one that is opened from about:debugging